# Show $c=rp^a$ is a quadratic residue modulo odd prime power $p^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

We are given:

1. odd prime $p$
2. $c=rp^a$, where $\gcd(r,p)=1 $  and  $1< a<n$
3. Algorithm $A$ that solves $x^2 \equiv c'\bmod p^n$ for all $c'\in \mathbb Z_p$

Now, we wish to find the solutions for $x^2\equiv c\bmod p^n$.
Moreover, we want to find the exact number of solutions.

I didn't managed to reach a good solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint: show that there are no solutions if $a$ is odd. If $a=2k$, show that any solution must satisfy $x=yp^k$ for some $y$. Then the solutions will be in 1-to-1 correspondence with the solutions of $y^2\equiv r\pmod{p^{n-a}}$.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thank you for the replay. what you wrote is right, but what I'm struggeling with is how to solve $y^2\equiv r (mod p^{n-a})$ since r is not necessarily in $\mathbb Z_p$ and algorithm A works only on $c' \in \mathbb Z_p$